# An amount kept at CI, earns an interest of Rs. 600 in the 7th year and an interest of Rs. 660 in the 8th year. Find the rate of interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An amount kept at CI, earns an interest of Rs. 600 in the 7th year and an interest of Rs. 660 in the 8th year. Find the rate of interest

Interest in 7th year= $P[1+r/100]^7-P=600$
Interest in 8th year= $P[1+r/100]^8-P=660$
I divided both the equation and ended up nowher
Answer is 10%

Comment: Well, the difference in the interest earned in consecutive years is the result of compounding.  That is, $60=660-600$ must equal $r\times .01\times 600$.

Comment: @lulu I am trying to understand the first sentence, but in the second sentence do you mean $60$ must equal $r\times 600$ rather than $r\times .01\times 600$ ? Or perhaps you mean that the rate is not $r$ itself, but $r \%$ ?

Comment: Whether you write $r$ or $\frac r{100}$ is up to you.  if the interest rate is ten percent does that mean $r=10$ or $r=.1$?  You wrote $\frac r{100}$ in your post so I assumed you preferred the answer $r=10$.This is purely a matter of notation, no content.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the statement of the problem and how to interpret it, that confuses you (which is kind of normal for this type of problems).

Say $x$ is the amount at the beginning of the $7$th year. My interpretation is that $xr=600$. Then $x(1+r)$ is the amount at the end of the $7$th year, which 
is the same as the beginning of the $8$th year, so my interpretation is that 
$x(1+r)r=660$. Expressing $x$ from each of these two equations we get 
$x=\frac{600}r=\frac{660}{(1+r)r}$, hence $(1+r)10=11$. Thus $10r=11-10=1$ and $r=0.1=10\%$.

The difference between my interpretation and yours is that I compute interest for the $7$th year *only* (disregarding the first $6$ years), whereas you seem to compute interest for the first $7$ years. Similarly I compute interest for the $8$th year *only*, and not for all the first $8$ years.